# Android text size causing drawable resource issue

Tags: android, screen-density

I have a TextView with a drawable as background. I've fiddle around the text size and realised that the text size had some issues with 5" and 6" devices. Is there any workaround for this? The background was slightly moved to the bottom which made the text not aligned in the center.

Edit: My drawable is a 9-patch bitmap. There isn't any code.

Issue (5"/6"):
[example http://cynxtech.com/image/test1234.jpg](http://cynxtech.com/image/test1234.jpg)

How it supposed to look like (7" and above):
[image: example1]
<sub>(source: [cynxtech.com](http://cynxtech.com/image/test123.png))</sub>

Comment: post your code so you can find here

Comment: You need to check the screen size & change text size accordingly.

Comment: upload the 9patch picture, and what are the height of the textView and the size of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Add background images in multiple drawable folders with correct same name. Then it define in programming like `FindViewByID.R.I'd("image_name")` without .PNG extension.